# Embedded H2 + Tomcat 7 JDBC realm + Hibernate = "Locked by another process"

Tags: java, hibernate, tomcat, jdbc, h2

Perhaps the title is self explanatory, but I am trying to create a web application with an embedded instance of the H2 database. I am configuring Tomcat 7 to use the JDBC realm to form-based authentication. `server.xml` has:

```
<Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JDBCRealm"
driverName="org.h2.Driver"
connectionURL="jdbc:h2:/someDir/myDB"
connectionName="userName"
connectionPassword="password"
userTable="user_enabled"
userNameCol="user_name"
userCredCol="pass"
userRoleTable="user_role"
roleNameCol="role_name" />
```

I am also using Hibernate for persistence. `persistence.xml` has:

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="org.h2.Driver" />
<property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:h2:/someDir/myDB" />
<property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="userName" />
<property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="password" />
<property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect" />
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="validate" />
<property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
<property name="current_session_context_class" value="org.hibernate.context.internal.ThreadLocalSessionContext" />
```

If I try to start the server I get:

```
(...) Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Database may be already in use: "Locked by another process".
```

And my web application fails to start.

Starting an H2 TCP server and replacing JDBC URLs with `jdbc:h2:tcp://myIP/` works fine. So no problem with my database files. Also, I am sure nothing else is trying to use those files. So the conflict can only be between the JDBC realm and Hibernate.

Why do I want an embedded server? For the classic reasons: I want to distribute this application and I don't want users to have to start two processes instead of just one. Also, this will not be a shared database, so no need to create a new process just for that. Finally, no additional server ports are open for database, which is good for security.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [H2 database error: Database may be already in use: “Locked by another process”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8158969/h2-database-error-database-may-be-already-in-use-locked-by-another-process).

Comment: It is not a duplicate. What is going on is the same, but it is an incompatibility between Tomcat JDBC realm and Hibernate. It is not my code what is causing the problem, therefore that question does not apply here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question, the way to make this work is by using a JNDI data source to access the database. For authentication, Tomcat should be configured to use the DataSourceRealm. So both Tomcat security and Hibernate will use the same embedded instance of H2, which does not cause the conflict I was experiencing.

Answer (score 0):

Though the JNDI data source is preferable, the original issue is that you are trying to create two connections to the same H2 database using a file or embedded database url. H2 does support this, but both of the processes would need to have ";AUTO_SERVER=true" appended to the connection url. This would cause the first connection to start the db in process in embedded mode, but would allow the seccond connection to connect through tcp ip.

Details are available here:

http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#auto_mixed_mode

Comment: Thanks for your message.

Yes, this is a possibility, but one that I tried to avoid. It is a bit odd to have an embedded DB that creates a server socket to which other processes on the same JVM have to connect to. Not only this is probably less performant but also unnecessarily opens a TCP port which can be a security concern and compete with other processes for the port.

AUTO_SERVER is great, but I guess it is a feature that fits other use cases.