# Database may be already in use error WSO2 API Manager and WSO2 Idenitity Server togother

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

```
Caused by: org.wso2.andes.kernel.AndesException: Connecting to database failed with jndi lookup : WSO2MBStoreDB. data source username : wso2carbon. SQL Error message : Database may be already in use: "Locked by another process". Possible solutions: close all other connection(s); use the server mode; SQL statement:
null/15996efd82ca04adc1f61035e9cbf980d7217681040 [90020-140]
        at org.wso2.andes.store.rdbms.RDBMSConnection.initialize(RDBMSConnection.java:66)
        at org.wso2.andes.store.rdbms.RDBMSAndesContextStoreImpl.init(RDBMSAndesContextStoreImpl.java:80)
        at org.wso2.andes.kernel.AndesKernelBoot.createAndesContextStoreFromConfig(AndesKernelBoot.java:215)
        at org.wso2.andes.kernel.AndesKernelBoot.startAndesStores(AndesKernelBoot.java:251)
        at org.wso2.andes.server.virtualhost.VirtualHostImpl.initialiseAndesStores(VirtualHostImpl.java:345)
        at org.wso2.andes.server.virtualhost.VirtualHostImpl.<init>(VirtualHostImpl.java:207)
        at org.wso2.andes.server.virtualhost.VirtualHostImpl.<init>(VirtualHostImpl.java:155)
        at org.wso2.andes.server.registry.ApplicationRegistry.createVirtualHost(ApplicationRegistry.java:568)
        at org.wso2.andes.server.registry.ApplicationRegistry.initialiseVirtualHosts(ApplicationRegistry.java:327)
        at org.wso2.andes.server.registry.ApplicationRegistry.initialise(ApplicationRegistry.java:261)
        ... 91 more
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Database may be already in use: "Locked by another process". Possible solutions: close all other connection(s); use the server mode; SQL statement:
null/15996efd82ca04adc1f61035e9cbf980d7217681040 [90020-140]
        at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbExceptio
```

I am getting this error.I am using MYSQL user store..And my datasources.xml looks like below

```
 <datasources>
      <datasource>

        <name>WSO2_CARBON_DB</name>
       <description>The datasource used for registry and user manager</description>
       <jndiConfig>
           <name>jdbc/WSO2CarbonDB</name>
       </jndiConfig>
       <definition type="RDBMS">
           <configuration>
               <url>jdbc:mysql:/mycloudIO:3306/apimgt?autoReconnect=true&amp;relaxAutoCommit=true&amp;</url>
               <username>regadmin</username>
               <password>regadmin</password>
               <driverClassName>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driverClassName>
               <maxActive>80</maxActive>
               <maxWait>60000</maxWait>
               <minIdle>5</minIdle>
               <testOnBorrow>true</testOnBorrow>
               <validationQuery>SELECT 1</validationQuery>
               <validationInterval>30000</validationInterval>
           </configuration>
       </definition>
</datasource>

        <datasource>
    <name>WSO2AM_DB</name>
    <description>The datasource used for API Manager database</description>
    <jndiConfig>
        <name>jdbc/WSO2AM_DB</name>
    </jndiConfig>
    <definition type="RDBMS">
        <configuration>  <url>jdbc:mysql://mycloudIO:3306/apimgt?autoReconnect=true&amp;relaxAutoCommit=true&amp;</url>
            <username>apiuser</username>
            <password>apimanager</password>
            <driverClassName>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driverClassName>
            <maxActive>50</maxActive>
            <maxWait>60000</maxWait>
            <testOnBorrow
```

Help Please

Comment: Error is from h2, not mysql. Do you have any h2 databases?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [H2 database error: Database may be already in use: "Locked by another process"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8158969/h2-database-error-database-may-be-already-in-use-locked-by-another-process)