# JIRA H2 Database: Could not successfully test your database

Tags: tomcat, jira, h2

Unfortunately, our VM rebooted automatically. As a result JIRA shutdown 
in an abrupt manner. When we tried to restart JIRA, tomcat is starting but we are unable to access JIRA via web browser.

We deleted `catalina.pid` & `.jira-home.lock` file. Yet, JIRA is not starting up.

We are getting the following error:

```
2018-11-14 14:10:40,508 JIRA-Bootstrap ERROR      [c.a.config.bootstrap.DefaultAtlassianBootstrapManager] Could not successfully test your database:
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Database may be already in use: "/app/atlassian/application-data/jira/database/h2db.mv.db". Possible solutions: close all other connection(s); use the server mode [90020-185]
```

From the logs it looks like a DB issue, and I don't know how to find if DB is receiving connections.

Can we kill the PID related with JIRA and restart JIRA?

Regards

Comment: Maybe look for and remove the H2 lock file? See https://stackoverflow.com/a/29058294/2220556. Also, H2 is only supported for evaluation purposes. If there is any data in Jira you care about, you really should configure it to use an external production dB.

Comment: @ScottDudley I browsed but didn’t find db lock file. Is there a way to migrate JIRA’s H2 data to Oracle DB or MSSQL?

Comment: Yes, XML export, set up the new DB, XML import. For smaller Jira DBs at least.

Comment: I assume you looked for a lock file in /app/atlassian/application-data/jira/database/? You might also try accessing the dB directly to see if it works (https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirakb/accessing-jira-s-h2-embedded-database-776818136.html). @mdoar's suggestion is the way to go for migration, but it admittedly requires that you first be able to start your instance while still running H2.

Comment: @ScottDudley Yes, I was looking in that folder. And regarding migration, I am unable to restart JIRA. So can’t I import?

Comment: @mdoar Thanks for the suggestion. And yes, our DB is small..:haha