# Cannot connect H2 database using Server Mode

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, h2, dbeaver

I use H2 database (file) in my Java app and due to some data appearance problem in IntelliJ, I use file option instead of memory.

Here is my url setting in `application.properties`:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:~/test-db;
    DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DATABASE_TO_UPPER=false;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE
```

I can connect and see table data via IntelliJ and H2 console by using the url parameter as shown below:

```
jdbc:h2:file:~/test-db
```

However, even I connect to the database successfully, the table data is not seen in DBeaver as shown below:

[image]

I think I should use `tcp` option to connect H2 daabase, but I cannot by using the following settings:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/~/test-db
```

or

```
jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/C:/test-db
```

and get "Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution" error (I use Windows). Any idea?

Comment: Does anybody else have never used **tcp** connection type for H2 database?

Answer (score 1):

You're using a file-associated connection to that in-memory DB that can only be used by 1 tool at once.
So when IntelliJ is connected it generates a lock-file to protect it against multi-access.

I would suggest a TCP connection that allows multiple connections - see redundant question here:
[H2 database error: Database may be already in use: "Locked by another process"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8158969/h2-database-error-database-may-be-already-in-use-locked-by-another-process)

Comment: Thanks  a lot, you right and I was trying to use tcp like this url: `spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/~/test-db` but it is not working. So, I already look at the connections strings, but not sure which one is the most proper for my situation and how can I convert my connection url for that?

Comment: I also tried with `jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/C:/test-db` (I use Windows) and get "*Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution*" error.

Comment: Amigo? Are you there?

Comment: @Jonathan sry for not responding: I would use the server mode for the H2 DB which allows then a real connection management. By default, just 1 connection can be applied.
Just add `;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE` to your default connection string and use TCP.

Comment: I solved the problem by following the steps on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43256295/how-to-access-in-memory-h2-database-of-one-spring-boot-application-from-another/43276769#43276769) page. Anyone who need to connect to H2 db in server mode can follow those steps. Thanks for help, voted up.